# AJAX is working only in Chrome not in Firefox or Android Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm super confused why my AJAX function works only in Chrome but not in other browsers.

I'm using Wordpress. I get the alert "function is called" but the AJAX request is not working, it shows nothing in the console.

```js
function get_calendar_id() {
  //alert("Function is Called");

  var data = {
    'action': 'get_cal_ids',
    'days': dates,
    'price': price,
    'stay': days
  };

  jQuery.post(ajax_object.ajax_url, data, function(response) {
    alert(response);
    document.getElementById("wpp_search_element_7898").value = response;
    document.getElementById("prop_search").submit();
    Console.log('Got this from the server: ', response);
  });
}
```

Comment: Something should be showing in the console, as `Console.log` is invalid. It should be `console.log`

Comment: it will work Firefox v49.0.2  and  above.

Comment: As Rory McCrossan has writen, `Console` is wrong, is should be `console`, also what jQuery version are you using

Comment: someone here said to use `Console` on Firefox, i tried both `Console`  and `console`  but that didn't help

Comment: @abhinavxeon  I'm on firefox v71